# How to Enable Jest & Enzyme to write tests using React on WebStorm

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, webstorm, enzyme

I am currently starting to learn about how to write tests in React and I am facing issues to make my IDE (Webstorm) recognize my `.test.js` files and apparently recognize `jest` itself.

On my course, a 2017 course, I have learned that `jest` would be set on my `package.json` file as it would be part of the `react-create-app` `library`. I did not identify the dependency installed at my `package.json` file inside the `"dependencies"` part when I started following up with the course module.

I had then installed `jest` along with the following dependencies as per listed below:

```
 "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
 "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2",
 "react-test-render": "^1.1.2",
 "enzyme-to-json": "^3.4.4",
```

The first issue was with a conflict of dependencies which had broken my app. It seems that the most recent version of `jest` is not accepted by `react-scrips` latest version `3.4.1`. So I had to downgrade the `jest` version to `24.9.0` in order to run my app again on development mode.

Then I have created a file to learn my first testing skills and I have noticed that `describe()` is not being recognized at all.

I don't know what to do to make it work. I don't know if this is still the best set up to write tests as well, as this is a 2017 `React` course.

Please see my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "veggie-burguers",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.4.4",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-test-render": "^1.1.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

After running `yarn test` I got two errors:

1st -

```
 Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(withRouter(App))". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(withRouter(App)) in connect options.

      4 | 
      5 | test('renders learn react link', () => {
    > 6 |   const { getByText } = render(<App />);
        |                         ^
      7 |   const linkElement = getByText(/learn react/i);
      8 |   expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
      9 | });
```

Question: Should I also set redux in my `App.test.js` file? It is all set up and working on my `root` `index.js` file

2nd -

```
 react-scripts test
 FAIL  src/components/Navigation/NavigationItems/NavigationItem/NavigationItems.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Your test suite must contain at least one test.
```

My above mentioned `test` file, namely `NavigationItems.test.js` is really empty, as obviously the `IDE` is not even recognizing `jest` inside of it when I write `describe()` it accuses the function to be `unresolved`.

In case there is more info needed I will update this enquiry accordingly.

Comment: jest is part of react-scripts package. you can manually go to the package.json file of react-scripts and check. When you run yarn test. Do you see any error?

Comment: @chandan_kr_jha Hello. I ge two errors: First - src/components/Navigation/NavigationItems/NavigationItem/NavigationItems.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Your test suite must contain at least one test.
That means that my ```NavigationItems.test.js``` is an empty file. That is alright and expected.

Comment: Second error - it seems that yarn is complaining that redux is not being recognized at the ```App.test.js``` root file. I have all of the ```redux``` config set up at my ```index.js``` file. Should I replicate all of my config at the ```App.test.js``` file as well?

Comment: As this first test of mine would be inside a presentation  ```component```, without ```state``` management, etc, so I think that these two errors should not stop me from having the ```describe()``` ```function``` being recognized inside ```NavigationItems.test.js```

Comment: Update your question with App.js and App.test.js. It would be easy to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: But I guess that my issue is not directly related to the ```App.test.js``` file, right? In my local testing file the IDE should recognize ```jest``` automatically. Should I need to set ```redux``` inside ```App.test.js```?

Comment: Refer this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/running-unit-tests-on-jest.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that Webstorm was not recognizing `jest` in my ...`test` files. So I have changed the title of the question here for this reason, which is just `IDE` related.

Solution :

In Webstorm => Preferences => Languages & Frameworks => JavaScript => Libraries, press `Download...`, select `'jest'` from the list of available stubs, press Download and Install.

After this, jest is recognized properly and I can use its features.